# Partitions of $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Trying to test my understanding of analysis, today I came up with two questions, that will probably look obvious (be patience, because I am self-thaught). Anyway, here they are:

1) Is possible to partition $[0,1]$ without giving any constraint to the nature of the elements of the partition (i.e. open, closed, etc)?

*My answer is yes. For example, $\{0\}, (0,1)$ and $\{1\}$ should form a trivial partition.*

2) Is possible to partition $[0,1]$ with open sets?

3) Is possible to partition $[0,1]$ with sets whose measure is not null?

*My answer to both questions (2) and (3) is no, but honestly I am a bit at loss.*

Thus, any feedback, help or answer is more than welcome.
Thanks is advance!

Comment: For 2), you have the trivial partition $\{[0,1]\}$ (if by "open" we mean open in $[0,1]$). No other partitions into open sets, in particular none into sets that are open in $\mathbb{R}$ [since $[0,1]$ is connected]. For 3), what about $\left\{\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]\,\left(\frac{1}{2},1\right]\right\}$?

Comment: If you wanted an even more trivial partition of $[0,1]$, just take $\{[0,1]\}$.  Also, $[0,1]$ is a set whose measure is not null, and thus $\{[0,1]\}$ is a partition with sets whose measure is not null.  For (2), I'd recommend thinking about whether you could partition it into finitely-many open sets; because $[0,1]$ is compact, any partition into open sets will necessarily be finite.  Also, open relative to what?  Open in $\mathbb{R}$, or open in $[0,1]$ in the subspace topology?  This is an important question to answer since it determines whether it is possible.

Comment: @Daniel: about (2) you are absolutely right, I should have mentioned that it was referred to $\Re$ and not to $[0,1]$; about (3), thanks a lot. Actually question (3) is really obvious.

Comment: @Hayden: Indeed, as I wrote to Daniel, that's absolutely right, I should have mentioned that I am looking for open sets in $\Re$. Just something, I don't see a clear connection between the finiteness of the open sets and problem (2): are you implicitly referring to the fact that this is an hint for a proof by contradiction that indeed the answer is no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 2: if you mean open sets in the whole real line, then you know that the union of open sets is open, hence it is not possible to obtain $[0,1]$. For 3, the partition with a single element is an answer. Or you can divide $[0,1]$ in $n$ equal parts of measure $1/n$ or in countable many parts each with decreasing measure $1/2^k$. If you want more than a countable parts, then yes, it is not possible that all have positive measure.